# Add database data to every razor view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

So I'm looking to get data from the database and add it to EVERY view page. So adding it to the Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

How can I do this without adding the models to the view in every controller?

I want to add menu items dynamically from the database to every view, I've got this in _Layout.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li><a href="/Cms/@item.Url">@item.Title</a></li>
}
```

And this in my HomeController:

```
return View(db.Menus.ToList());
```

But I don't want to do this in every controller action, how can I make this simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to render only the part you want.

I strongly encourage you to check [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) project - it has a lot of best practices in it. The solution for your exact problem lies in [_Layout.cshtml](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MvcMusicStore/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) file, the code:

```
   @{Html.RenderAction("GenreMenu", "Store");}
```

Comment: Isnt the mvc music store project based on MVC3? I'm using MVC5 i think

Comment: It is for MVC3. But these are basics that have not changed from MVC3. By the way MVC5 has been released not so long ago and it is too early to judge which practices are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a model, which represents your menu in your database

```
class MenuItem()
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  //...
}
```

In order to get this into every viewpage, you need to create a "BaseController", from which every other controller inherits. In this controller you define the menu in the constructor.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
 {  
    public BaseController()
    {
        //I don't know how you get your data
        ViewBag.DatabaseMenu =  repository.GetMenuItems();
    }
 }
```

Fromn this point on add `: BaseController` to all your controllers and you'll have a `DatabaseMenu` available in your ViewBag on all pages to build your menu from.

How you do this in your view, is up to you. You can create a collection of type `List<MenuItem>` and say `List<MenuItem> Menu = ViewBag.DatabaseMenu;` and iterate with foreach over your items to create the menu